# What is the term for the relationship between two words when they have similar but not identical pronunciation?

Tags: pronunciation, poetry

What is the term for the relationship between two words when they have similar but not identical pronunciation? For example the words "cheat" and "sheet", "core" and "sour", "think" and "thank", "tough" and "cuff" sound very similar. I am not talking in the context of poetry but to clarify these words may be used in poetry.

**PS:**
The only thing I care about is how two words sound in ear. I don't care if there is a category to which a pair of words mentioned above belongs or if such a category does not exist: "core" is similar to "sour" because a human can understand it and can understand "core" is far from "black" without providing any reason.

Comment: Important: If you mean the context of poetry (as noted from the tag list) then please state that in the body of the question as well.

Comment: Thanks everyone! I haven't down-voted any answer yet. I think some examples may clarify: "core" and "sour", "think" and "thank", "tough" and "cuff"

Comment: 'Cheat' and 'sheet' are rhymes, 'core' and 'sour' are half-rhymes, 'think' and 'thank' don't even make it that far.

Comment: _Core_ and _sour_ aren't even any kind of rhyme. The only thing they have in common is that they end in an /r/—they rhyme no more than _was_ and _Nepalese_.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  April Fools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called a slant rhyme, or oblique rhyme.

Comment: Slant or oblique (also known as "half") rhymes use similar, but not identical, sounding words, just as the original question describes.

Comment: Note that the question describes a slant rhyme, but gives as an example an ordinary rhyme.

Comment: My answers *should* include enough information to move the one asking the question to consult references, without resorting to the off-putting "look it up!"

Comment: No, your answers should be **complete in themselves,** including all information which might be useful. The aim of Stack Exchange is to be a compendium of answers, not a directory of pointers.

Comment: An answer "complete in itself" is impossible when discussing language. To demand such an answer reveals a deep incomprehension of language.

Comment: On ELU, answers should not be given when the question is manifestly unclear. A request for clarification in a comment may be appropriate. But here, 'rhyme' is hardly a word that should be being requested on this website, and 'oblique rhyme' has already been covered [answered Jul 18 '11 by Robusto].

Comment: Call me ignorant but I don't understand the difference between a slant rhyme and a normal rhyme, which means I will have to Google these terms myself. You haven't even thought about providing a suitable link. If I am not an expert how will I know which source is reliable, and which are superficial or just plain misleading.

Comment: back and with a link http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half_rhyme ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are referring to a common technique used in poetry to create a musical effect: [rhyme](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/rhyming)

> - Correspondence of terminal sounds of words or of lines of verse.
> - A word that corresponds with another in terminal sound, as fold and cold.

(TFD)

Comment: I didn't downvote this correct answer, but I understand why it may have been downvoted (unless somebody is hopelessly off target): surely it would have been better to close-vote / downvote / flag the question.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - I think it is a *basic* but acceptable question.

Comment: Now I'll downvote. **If** OP is requesting the term 'rhyme', I'd say that's too basic a question for ELL.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - we actually don't know what the term OP is looking for is. Anywhay you have   downvoted something you have just defined as *correct answer*!!

Comment: FumbleFingers has commented elsewhere '[W]e should seek to discourage people from providing trivial answers to trivial [I'd say elementary]  questions. We all like to be helpful, but the place for that level of help is English Language Learners....

Comment: He also writes:  'Premature pre-emptive answers are no benefit to the site, so I [can’t] see any problem with them being downvoted if they don't answer the "final, clarified" question. If nothing else, this might discourage those hasty answerers from leaving what eventually amounts to "litter" on the site.' This would be an unfair reason to downvote your answer, since only on OP's editing do we know that he includes rhymes and oblique rhymes. ("cheat" and "sheet", "core" and "sour", "think" and "thank" (?!) ) The main reason to close this question now is that it is a duplicate.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - the question in the meantime has been improved and it now probably more acceptable. I do agree that poor quality questions are to be discouraged :))

Comment: The question now is too broad, including both rhymes and slant rhymes. One doesn't discourage poor quality questions by answering them (or what one thinks the questions are).

Answer (score 0):

Words that have only one phonological difference between them are called [**minimal pairs**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_pair).

Answer (score -1):

It should be a homophone or a heterograph.

**Homophone**: words with different meaning; same or different spelling; same pronunciation
**Heterograph**: words with different meaning; different spelling; same pronunciation

Check: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homophone

Comment: "Same" pronunciation is not my intention. "Similar" is enough.

Answer (score -4):

I think you are thinking, "homonym"

Comment: Please explain what a homonym is!